# Как правильно настроить https в ispmanager для конкретного домена?

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, администрирование, ssl

На сервере freebsd стоит ISPmanager-Lite 4.4.10.28, и веб сервер под управлением nginx+apache

На сервере есть несколько сайтов(доменов) и проблема в том, что если задать хотя-бы одному из них галочку ssl, то и остальные сайты становятся доступны по https, при этом, конечно, отображается ошибка наподобие такой:

> Не удалось подтвердить, что это сервер domain.ru. Его сертификат
>   безопасности относится к www.ssldomain.ru. Возможно, сервер настроен
>   неправильно или кто-то пытается перехватить

Если снять галочку ssl у всех доменов, то https перестает отвечать.
Галочка добавляет в nginx конфиг следующие строки:

```
server {
    ............
    server_name ssldomain.ru;
    ............
    listen 89.108.121.130:443 ssl;
    ............
    ssl_certificate /home/httpd-cert/user/cert.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/httpd-cert/user/cert.key;
  }
```

К остальным доменам эти строки не добавляются.
Как сделать что-бы нужный мне домен отвечал по https, а остальные нет?
Спасибо!

Comment: работали с isp 4 lite, но таких ошибок не было. попробуйте на **[форум ispsystems](http://forum.ispsystem.ru/)** написать и/или обновить до последней стабильной версии.

Answer (score 1):

если другие домены у вас резолвятся в тот же ip-адрес, то у вас не выйдет «оградить» ни один из доменов от ssl-соединений. сначала устанавливается ssl-соединение, а уже потом можно сделать что-нибудь «ограждающее»: вернуть ошибку, сделать перенаправление и т.п.

вольный перевод [ответа с другого сайта](https://serverfault.com/a/593427/292034) с дополнениями:

без *sni (server name indication)* доменное имя (*hostname*) — это часть зашифрованной информации (и доступна она для расшифоровки становится лишь после установления ssl-соединения).

но даже со *sni* браузер не примет перенаправления от сервера без установки ssl-соединения (https handshake + validation).